# How to add React tooltip on start of empty input field

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';


const DataInputBox = () => {

  return (
      <div>     
        <ReactTooltip id="title required"effect="solid" place="bottom" >
           "Title required"
        </ReactTooltip>
        <input
          type="text"
          data-tip
          data-for="title required"
          placeholder="Type title"
          name="title"
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DataInputBox;
```

Not able to get tooltip at bottom start of input box.Can anyone please help me to get tooltip at cursor start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ref` to input element and pass this ref to `ReactTooltip.show()` method.

```
const DataInputBox = () => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
       ReactTooltip.show(inputRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactTooltip id="title required" efect="solid" place="bottom">
        "Title required"
      </ReactTooltip>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={inputRef}
        data-tip
        data-for="title required"
        placeholder="Type title"
        name="title"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What's the use of ref? Even though without using ref i'm able to get tootip but it is at middle of the field. I want at beginning of the field where cursor focus.

Comment: In your question you've asked about how to show tooltip at start, not about alignment :)